# Checking string defined array elements with a for loop

Tags: c#

I apologize in the first place if i fail to express myself correctly, as my english is not particularly good.

So, my problem is, i am trying to write a code about exam stimulation in c#. I'm %99 percent done and right now i am trying to shorten my code. My exact question is:

`for (int a = 2; a <= 4; a++)
if (candidates[i, a] == "1"`

in this example, can we change checking "1" string value depending on a for loop?  i want it to take the string value of whatever 'a' value currenly looping inside.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "i want it to take the string value of whatever 'a' value currenly looping inside." - I'm afraid I don't understand that part at all. Could you give a complete example of what you're trying to achieve? It's quite hard to understand your question at the moment.

Comment: If I understand right, you can just do "candidates[i,a] == a", it will check if there's a number (2,3 or 4) inside

Comment: Oh, I think I've figured what you want. It should be "candidates[i,a] == a.ToString()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
candidates[i,a] == a.ToString()
```

"a.ToString()" represents the string version of a number 'a'

ToString() method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: so basic yet worked wonderfully. well, every day a new information! thanks a lot!!

Comment: @ÇağdaşKemik You're right about new info every day, that's exactly like that in this industry. Would you mind accepting my answer, if it's worth it? I just like green colors, you know

Comment: sorry for the late answer.. I just did! thanks a ton again:)